# SQL query to get Column A with all Column B

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a table that has 2 columns customer and city . there are 4 unique cities (w,x,y,z) I want customers that is associated with all cities. So for the table

```
+----------+------+
| Customer | City |
+----------+------+
| A        | W    |
| A        | X    |
| A        | Y    |
| A        | Z    |
| B        | X    |
| C        | Y    |
| Z        | X    |
| Z        | Y    |
+----------+------+
```

the desired output is

```
+----------+------+
| Customer | City |
+----------+------+
| A        | W    |
| A        | X    |
| A        | Y    |
| A        | Z    |
+----------+------+
```

Query I used was :

```
Select Customer,City
From Table As T
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From Table As T2
                Where T2.Customer = T.City
                    And T2.City<> T.City
                )
```

Comment: On a side note: You should have three tables; one for the customers, one for the cities, and one for the relation between the two. Otherwise, with one table only, a mere typo like 'New Yorc' in one of the rows could make your query not return any data. But you probably know this already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With aggregation and the condition in the HAVING clause you can get the customers that you want:

```
select customer
from tablename
group by customer
having count(*) = (select count(distinct city) from tablename)
```

and you can use it with the operator IN:

```
select * from tablename
where customer in (
  select customer
  from tablename
  group by customer
  having count(*) = (select count(distinct city) from tablename)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, @forpas. just a follow-up question if I tried to pivot the column using a case statement and the use 'AND' would that be the right approach. I didn't want to do that as it will make the query long and unreadable

Comment: @Sam the only way that something like what you describe would work is with as many EXISTS statements as the number of distinct cities and not with a CASE expression, so I don't think that this is the right approach.